# How to create a new dataframe based on dtypes from an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposed I have this DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':['foo', 'bar','foo'], 
                  'val': [1,2,3]})
df['cat'] = df['cat'].astype('category')
```

So, its `dtypes` (`df.dtypes`) correspond to:

```
cat    category
val       int64
dtype: object
```

One option would be to simply use the columns:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
```

However, this would not preserve the `dtypes` (`new_df.dtypes`):

```
cat    object
val    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way. You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.astype`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
new_df = pd.dataFrame(columns = df.columns).astype(dtype = df.dtypes)

new_df.dtypes
cat    category
val       int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy an empty version of the initial DataFrame. In the example you provided, just do this:

```
new_df = df[df.index != df.index].copy()
```

Running `new_df.dtypes` should give you the expected categories:

```
cat    category
val       int64
dtype: object
```